# How to do double indirect expansion in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command

I am trying to pass a color name as a parameter to change the font color for that print. I'd like to also print type of message like INFO, ERR, SUCC, CMD etc depending on the color passed.

function is

```
red=ERR
grn=SUCC
yel=WARN
blu=INFO
mag=STAT
cyn=CMD

ERR=31
SUCC=32
WARN=33
INFO=34
STAT=35
CMD=36

end=$'\e[0m'

Print() {
    printf "\033[1;${!{!1}}m${!1} $3\033[0m\n"
}
```

and called using

```
Print red "text"
```

***Expected output***

```
[ ERR] text <------IN RED
```

***Actual output***

```
*\033[1;${!{!1}}m${!1} $3\033[0m\n: bad substitution*
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to do double indirect expansion in bash?

It can't be done directly. But it can be done indirectly, it's just one line more:

```
Print() {
    msg=${!1}
    printf "\033[1;${!msg}m[${msg}] $2\033[0m\n"
}
```

Notice that `$3` was wrong, it should be `$2`.